# How do I fix a gap in my refrigerator door gasket seal?

Tags: refrigerator, sealing

Today I noticed that the gasket seal surrounding the refrigerator door has a bit of a gap along the lower quarter of the door. The photo below shows my refrigerator door - notice how the white gasket is flush with the refrigerator from the top down to about six inches below the bottom of the door handle, but then there is a gap that starts to grow and runs down to the end of the door.

[image: Gap in the refrigerator door insulation.]

How would I go about fixing this gap? Do I need to buy a new strip of the door gasket and replace the existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Measure the space between the door and refrigerator on all sides/corners to see if something is out of alignment. One of the steps in replacing most gaskets is to fix the alignment of the door before tightening the screws. To fix the alignment, you would loosen the gasket screws, push or pull the top and bottom corners of the door until it's properly aligned, and retighten the gasket screws.

See [these instructions](http://www.doorseal.com.au/fittingguides/d4-fitting-instructions) on the steps to replace a gasket to get a better idea of the steps involved.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. With the door open the insulation is clearly "squished" where the gap is. It does not extend as far out as the insulation above.

Comment: In that case, you'll likely have to replace the entire gasket.  Here are some sample instructions that will put you on the right path, but review the instructions that come with the replacement seal: http://www.doorseal.com.au/fittingguides/d4-fitting-instructions

Comment: I broke down and called an appliance repairman. Your initial assessment was correct - he reseated the door and the gap no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

My gap was similar but bigger. I realigned the fridge to lean back vs level, took the beer out of the door, and applied vaseline to the gasket. Much improved.

Answer (score 0):

My first attempt was my gf's blow dryer. I let it get good and hot so it would be plyable. Helped but not 100%.  So I grabbed some EZ squeeze caulking I had lying around and applied a thin layer around the area where the gap was. Seems to be holding for now. If it doesn't last I'll do my best to update this.