# Refrigerator door seal is developing a gap towards the bottom. Not sure it is letting air through

Tags: refrigerator, gap, seal

Nobody has been leaning on the door but there is now a 1/4 inch gap towards the bottom (beginning about halfway down) unless it is pushed closed tightly.

I think this is just the outer part of the seal - it is about an inch wide - and maybe it is not allowing air exchange with the room.

I have no idea how they are attached nor where I would buy a new one.

Is there a home remedy for this minor annoyance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is found here:

[How can I eliminate a gap in a refrigerator door gasket?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47774/how-can-i-eliminate-a-gap-in-a-refrigerator-door-gasket)

which points also to

[How do I fix a gap in my refrigerator door gasket seal?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/how-do-i-fix-a-gap-in-my-refrigerator-door-gasket-seal)

It is a door alignment issue.

Simply loosening the screws at the bottom on the hinge side and raising it a bit down there fixed it.